# How compute weighted accuracy for multi-class classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I do multi-class classification on unbalanced classes. I'm using `SGDClassifier(), GradientBoostingClassifier(), RandomForestClassifier(), and LogisticRegression()`with `class_weight='balanced'`. To compare the results. it is required to compute the accuracy. I tried the following way to compute weighted accuracy:

```
n_samples = len(y_train)
weights_cof = float(n_samples)/(n_classes*np.bincount(data[target_label].as_matrix().astype(int))[1:])
sample_weights = np.ones((n_samples,n_classes)) * weights_cof
print accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weights)
```

`y_train` is a binary array. So `sample_weights` has the same shape as `y_train` (`n_samples, n_classes`). When I run the script, I received the following error:

**Update:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:/Destiny/DestinyScripts/MainLocationAware.py", line 424, in <module>
    predict_country(featuresDF, score, featuresLabel, country_sample_size, 'gbc')
  File "D:/Destiny/DestinyScripts/MainLocationAware.py", line 313, in predict_country
    print accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weights)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 183, in accuracy_score
    return _weighted_sum(score, sample_weight, normalize)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 108, in _weighted_sum
    return np.average(sample_score, weights=sample_weight)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1124, in average
    "Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights "
TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

Comment: So, do you want to make us guess which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga The error is related to accuracy_score() function.

Comment: Why don't you just post the full error message, and the stack trace?

Comment: In the error message you are passing `accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred, sample_weight=weights_cof)` in the code you posted, instead of `accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weights)`

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I also replaced the `weights_cof` with `sample_weights` to see if the error resolved, but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

The error would seem to suggest that the shape of your sample_weights and your `y_test`/`y_pred` arrays differ. Basically the method creates a boolean array with `y_test == y_pred` and passes that along with `sample_weights` to `np.average`. One of the first checks in that method is to ensure that the entered array and the weights are the same shape, which apparently in this case they are not.

### Update

Your comment "sample_weights, y_test, and y_pred have the same shape (n_samples, n_classes)" exposes the issue. According to the documentation for [`accuracy_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), `y_pred` and `y_true` (in your case `y_test` and `y_pred`) should be 1 dimensional. Are you perhaps using one hot encoded labels? If so you should convert them to single value labels and then try the accuracy score again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have checked the shapes. `sample_weights, y_test, and y_pred` have the same shape (n_samples, n_classes).